# How to find MLE and MAP of a Poisson distribution?

Tags: self-study, distributions, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, posterior

Can someone explain how to find out the Maximum Likelihood and Maximum A Posteriori Estimate for a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ ?

I did the calculation for the MLE as follows:

The probability mass function is: $$f(y;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!}$$

Assume we have only one observation $y$. This implies that the log-likelihood is:

$$\ell(\lambda;y) = y\log(\lambda) - \lambda$$

and the score function is: 
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\lambda} [\ell(\lambda;y)] = \frac y \lambda - 1$$

Setting the score equal to 0 we obtain:

$$y/\lambda - 1 = 0$$ and the MLE is $$\hat\lambda = k$$

I know this is the MLE since the second derivative of $\ell(\lambda;y)$ at $\hat\lambda$ is negative, i.e. it is $(- 1/y)$.

I can't figure out how to approach MAP calculation though. I am using a Gamma distribution with alpha and beta as its parameters.

Comment: have you at least tried to do some calculations by yourself? What do you obtain? Which is the prior you are using?

Comment: Hello, I added the question with the calculations I did for the MLE estimation.

Comment: `[self-study]` tag may be appropriate in here, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: See Tim's comment above. If you take the derivative of the logarithm of the gamma prior times the likelihood and then set it to zero, what do you obtain?

Comment: This seems to meet our standards for SS questions: the OP added the tag & has explained what they understand thus far.